# match width of similar elements in rows of a list

Tags: html, css

I have a list of links. Each link has different parts. I don't know the widths of each part as it will change at run time but I want each matching part to be the same width. The result would be similar to if I used a table where each column has the same width but I can't use a table because I want each "row" to be a continuous `a` element.

This is what I have.

```css
* { text-decoration: none }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">asdf</span> - <span class="part2">defdef</span> - <span class="part3">ghij</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">adf</span> - <span class="part2">de</span> - <span class="part3">ghij</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">asdfasdf</span> - <span class="part2">d</span> - <span class="part3">ghij</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">asdfa</span> - <span class="part2">defd</span> - <span class="part3">ghij</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">a</span> - <span class="part2">defde</span> - <span class="part3">ghij</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

This is what I want the output to look like except I can't set a specific width since I won't know how much text is in each part until run-time.

```css
* { text-decoration: none }
.part1 { display: inline-block; width: 55px }
.part2 { display: inline-block; width: 45px }
.part3 { display: inline-block; width: 35px }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">asdf</span> - <span class="part2">defdef</span> - <span class="part3">ghij</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">adf</span> - <span class="part2">de</span> - <span class="part3">ghij</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">asdfasdf</span> - <span class="part2">d</span> - <span class="part3">ghij</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">asdfa</span> - <span class="part2">defd</span> - <span class="part3">ghij</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">a</span> - <span class="part2">defde</span> - <span class="part3">ghij</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that, you'll have to order your information in vertical columns, rather than horizontally - that way, the width of the longest item determines the width of the entire column

```css
ul {
  float:left;
  padding:0;
}
li {
  list-style:none;
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
span {
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">asdf</span> </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">adf</span> </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part1">asdfasdf</span> </a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part2">defdef</span> </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part2">de</span> </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part2">d</span> </a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part3">ghij</span> </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part3">ghij</span> </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="part3">ghij</span> </a></li>
</ul>
```

:

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you very much!